How to calculate 2 Different Date time into month/year/days on Excel?
I am using Office365, and I try to use formula =DATEDIF(A2;B2;"m") , but it seems it doesn't work, it shown #NUM

I want to know the outcome result in Month or days between 2 date please, thank you

First paramater has to be the earlier date --> B2 in your case --> DATEDIF(B2;A2;"m") --> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38

ugh Wow, Thank Ike, you just made my day!

So, two versions:

Dates are formatted as dates. You could get the months to include a decimal by dividing by 30 or 31 or you could get the number of days for th relevant months... Left for you as an exercise.
